# Magento 2 placeholder svg

Tags: magento, magento2

Replaced the file /vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml, but still when trying to download the "Forbidden file type" error through the admin panel of placeholder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SVG format was removed since 2.1.9 because of **security issues**. Search for SVG here:
https://magento.com/security/patches/magento-2.0.16-and-2.1.9-security-update

If you really want to revert back those changes, which I definitely not recommend, search here for SVG so you can see what was removed:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/compare/2.1.8...2.1.9

It is a comparison between Magento 2.1.9 and the previous version 2.1.8.